# Consulta mysql resultados repetidos

Tags: mysql

Esta Consulta mysql me dá algunos resultados repetidos...un mensaje de tipo."

***La selección actual no contiene una columna única. La edición de la grilla y los enlaces de copiado, eliminación y edición no están disponibles.***

```
SELECT 
  `horasobra`.`trabajador`,
  `horasobra`.`horas`,
  `horasobra`.`horasX`,
  `horasobra`.`st`,
  `horasobra`.`Fecha`,
  `otrostrabajodores`.`PrecioHora`,
  (`horas` * `PrecioHora`) AS `thoras`,
  `otrostrabajodores`.`PrecioHoraX`,
  (`horasx` * `PrecioHorax`) AS `thorasx`,
  `st`.`id`
FROM
  `horasobra`
  INNER JOIN `otrostrabajodores` ON (`horasobra`.`trabajador` = `otrostrabajodores`.`idTrabajador`)
  INNER JOIN `st` ON (`horasobra`.`idst` = `st`.`id`)
WHERE
  `st`.`id` =291
```

Repite los registros marcados en Rojo...

Alguna sugerencia...

Gracias...chavales...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura tabla horasobra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura tabla otrostrabajodores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura tabla st

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pásanos la estructura de la base de datos en SQL con algunos datos de ejemplo, con phpmyadmin->exportar, e indícanos qué te gustaría obtener para esos datos de muestra y cómo llegarías a ese resultado manualmente.

Comment: podrias agregar el dise;o de tu tabla con `show create table tablename;`

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Hay varios datos distintos en los registros que dices que son *repetidos*. Por ejemplo, la `Fecha` es distinta. Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema.